# how to search word in a line of file correct

Tags: python

I have the text file file1.txt. which contains lines as

```
test_file_work(list: 2, Result =0)

test_file_work_list(list: 5, Result =0)

test_file_work_list(list: 6, Result =0)

test_file_work(list: 2, Result =5)

test_file_work_list(list: 6, Result =0)
```

How to find in all the lines in the file result=0

My code:

```
fo=open("file1.txt","r")
for line in fo.readlines():
    if re.search(r"test_(.*)(list)(.*),result=0,line):
        print "ok"
    else:
        print "mismatch"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the lines pattern will be always the same you can do:

```
fo=open("file1.txt","r")
for line in fo.readlines():
    if 'Result =0' in line:
        print "ok"
    else:
        print "mismatch"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print [line for line in open("somefile") if "Result =0" in line]
```

is probably the simplest way ... at least imho

there are many many ways to accomplish this though

although I suspect you want something more like

```
a_generator = (line for line in open("somefile") if "Result =0" in line)
print [re.findall("list: \d+",line) for line in a_generator]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("in.txt","r") as fo: # use with to open files, it closes them automatically
    for line in fo.readlines():
        if line.strip(): # skip empty lines
            if line.rstrip()[-2] == '0': # remove `\n`
                print "ok"
            else:
                print "mismatch"
```

If you want to check for two substrings in your string you  don't need re:

```
with open("in.txt","r") as fo: # use with to open files, it closes them automatically
        for line in fo.readlines():
                if "Result =0" in line and "test_file_work_list" in line : 
                    print "ok"
                else:
                    print "mismatch"
```

Or use `if all(x in line for x in ["Result =0","test_file_work_list"])`

If you want to extract the lines:

```
with open("Hello.txt","r") as fo:
    f = fo.readlines()
    lines = [ele for ele in f if  all(y in ele for y in ["Result =0","test_file_work_list"])]
```

Comment: I want to match the line using re.search or something else

Comment: why do you want to use re?

Comment: because test_file_work(list: 2, Result =0)
test_file_work_list(list: 5, Result =0) are different lines but Result=0 for both line. i want to check only in test_file_work_list

Comment: @gokul, you can check for two substrings without re